# Conditionally include SSL configuration and use variables for proxy_pass

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have an Nginx configuration that serves both HTTP and HTTPS traffic. Here's the existing configuration:

```
server {
client_max_body_size 7M;
listen 80;
listen [::]:80;
server_name webmsh.com www.webmsh.com;

# Redirect HTTP traffic to HTTPS
return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
client_max_body_size 7M;
listen 443 ssl;
listen [::]:443 ssl;
server_name example.com;

ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/certificates/fullchain.pem;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/certificates/privkey.pem;
# Other SSL settings can be added here
location / {
    proxy_pass http://host.docker.internal:3002/;
 }
}
```

Now, I want to make two modifications:

Use a variable for proxy_pass:
I want to set proxy_pass as a variable so that it can be easily modified. For example, if I want to change the backend server, I can do it by modifying a single variable.

Conditionally include SSL configuration:
I want to introduce another variable, let's call it $ssl_enabled. If the value of $ssl_enabled is "no," I want the configuration to be simple like this

```
server{
client_max_body_size 2048M;
listen 80;
listen [::]:80;
 server_name : example;

location /{
proxy_pass "http://host.docker.internal:3001/";
}
}
```

and if it is yes then it should behave exactly like first code